Wordpress Woocommerce - filter by attribute with condition OR by query params
Each wheel can have two different bolt patterns ( attribute )
bolt-pattern, bolt-pattern-2

When I filter by specific car I use query param and filter like this

https://wheeluniverse.com/YMM/wheels/?**filter_bolt-pattern=6X139-7**&query_type_finish=or&orderby=recommended

This will then open the page filtered by that bolt pattern where end user can filter further by attributes : Brand, Color .....
Question: How can I set the condition "OR" for bolt-patterns this means
filter_bolt-pattern=6X139-7  or  filter_bolt-pattern-2=6X139-7
I tried with generic query params but doesn't seem so easy.
https://wheeluniverse.com/YMM/wheels/?orderby=recommended&filter_bolt-pattern=6x139-7&filter_bolt-pattern-2=6x139-7&query_type_bolt-pattern-2=or


With the Wordpress and WooCommerce installed you can achive it this way:

check the query args and see if both of the attributes are involved. It means in the query args you should have filter_bolt-pattern=6x139-7&filter_bolt-pattern-2=6x139-7
using that you can have an if statement that checks if both of them are there inorder to modify the woocommerce query.

The hooks you want to connect to:
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'filter_products_by_bolt_pattern_or');
and here is the function:
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'filter_products_by_bolt_pattern_or');

function filter_products_by_bolt_pattern_or( $q ) {
    if (isset($_GET['filter_bolt-pattern']) && isset($_GET['filter_bolt-pattern-2'])) {
        $tax_query = array('relation' => 'OR');

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_bolt-pattern',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $_GET['filter_bolt-pattern'],
        );

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_bolt-pattern-2',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $_GET['filter_bolt-pattern-2'],
        );

        $q->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    }
}

Also keep it in mind that using the value of the $_GET like this is not a good aproach in case of security. you should sanitize and escape the values.
You can read this document about the security of these data: https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/escaping/

Thank you for your answer, for some reason I still can't get it working Var dumped link

Working examples to show correct data Filter by first only.  Filter by second only
